# Testing helm charts in github action

Tags: testing, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How do you add additional `values.yaml` files to `helm/chart-testing-action`?

Something like `helm lint -f my-values.yaml`.

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use --values or --set to add additional values to chart.

```
Example:

helm install helm/chart-testing-action  -f <Value file>

or 

helm install helm/chart-testing-action --values <Value file>
```